# What do search engines think when they see meta "description" and meta "keywords" are identical?

Tags: seo

If meta description and meta keywords are identical, is that considered "bad" for search engines?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the behaviour of search engine services / asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meta description and meta keywords tags are not used by the major search engines as part of their ranking algorithms so the question really is moot. (The keyword is generally ignored and is widely accepted as having no SEO value. The meta description tag does not affect rankings but Google *may* use it as the snippet shown when your web page is displayed in their search results.)

But to answer your question, if your meta keyword and description tags are identical then you are using them incorrectly. The meta keywords tag should be a comma delimited list of keywords that best represent the content of the page. The meta description tag should be a one or two sentence summary of the page. If you are using a comma delimited list as your description then your description tag is poorly implemented. If you have sentences or blocks of text in your keywords tag then that tag is poorly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.9% sure all of the big engines (Google, Yahoo, Bing) completely ignore the keywords field and they use the description for the search page but not for page rankings.

So to answer your questions...no it's not bad for search engines because they don't acknowledge them.

Answer (score 0):

from this website :http://www.wordsinarow.com/seo.html

I got that The "keyword"  tag used to be important but is basically useless now.

so I would agree with cubed Eye Studios that it renders obsolete, and I wouldn't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Most ignore keywords, but description and title are important..